# Use of Vert to display inequalities

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to display three inequalities and naturally each one needs to stand in its own line. The problem is I need to use the symbol given by the `\Vert` command on their left and I can't get them into separate lines. Can anyone please help me sort this issue out?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%opening
\title{Esercizi svolti}

\begin{document}
\[
+\Bigg \Vert \sqrt{n} > 0\\
n^2\sqrt{n} > 0\\
2n^2-12\sqrt{n}+6>0
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\[` is a single line equation, you have loaded the `amsmath` package but not using its environments for multiline math displays such as `align*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for your comment, the problem is only the first inequality gets the vertical bars on the left, the others are in fact on their own line but "pushed out of" the bars.

Comment: @haunted85 With that code you get no line break, so it's quite hard to guess what you mean by “pushed out of the bars”.  And I can't guess what the final result should be.

Comment: `\\ ` has _no effect_ inside `\[` your equation is all on one line.

Comment: also you don't need to load `amsmath` package as long as you load `mathtools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{fullpage}

%opening
\title{Esercizi svolti}

\begin{document}
\[
+\left\|
\begin{aligned}
& \sqrt{n} > 0\\
& n^2\sqrt{n} > 0\\
& 2n^2-12\sqrt{n}+6>0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Don't forget `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` when the document is in Italian.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this (obtainable in two different ways):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%opening
\title{Esercizi svolti}

\begin{document}
\[
{}+\left \Vert\;\begin{aligned} & \sqrt{n} > 0\\
 & n^2\sqrt{n} > 0\\
 & 2n^2-12\sqrt{n}+6 >0
\end{aligned}\right. \]

\[\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
{}+\,\begin{array}{||>{\displaystyle}l} \sqrt{n} > 0\\
  n^2\sqrt{n} > 0\\
 2n^2-12\sqrt{n}+6 >0
\end{array} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]